How to use the Google in app navigation sdk in flutter
Navigation SDK
The link to sdk is here
https://mapsplatform.google.com/maps-products/navigation-sdk/?utm_source=gamma&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=GMP-global-Maps-email-of-GMP-gamma-email&utm_content=NavSDK_launch_2024
Build in-app navigation.
The navigation sdk is available for native ios and Android but how can I use it in flutter to have in app navigation
Im trying to use the navigation sdk but can't use it in flutter? Can anyone help me

Could you please raise a feature request in Google Public Issue Tracker?
